# How can I get the number of deleted records?

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe4

I tried this:

```
function TMyClass.removeRecords(...) : integer;
var
  aC : TADOCommand;
  aRS : _RecordSet;
begin
  aC := createADOCommand;
  try
    aC.Connection := fConnection;
    aC.commandText := getDeleteModelSQLCommand( ... );
    aRS := aC.Execute;
    {$ifdef debug_AlwaysOne}
      result := 1;
    {$else}
      result := aRS.RecordCount;
    {$endif}
  finally
    releaseADOCommand( aC );
  end;
end;
```

It runs correctly with the `debug_AlwaysOne` conditional defined.

However, at the line that reads the `RecordCount`, it raises an error:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Is there any way to get the number of removed records? I know I can execute an aggregate query before deletion. But can I do this without another SQL command call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the overloaded version of [`TADOCommand.Execute()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOCommand.Execute) that has a `RecordsEffected` output parameter:

```
function Execute(var RecordsAffected: Integer; const Parameters: OleVariant): _Recordset; overload;
```

For example:

```
function TMyClass.removeRecords(...) : integer;
var
  aC : TADOCommand;
begin
  aC := createADOCommand;
  try
    aC.Connection := fConnection;
    aC.commandText := getDeleteModelSQLCommand( ... );
    {$ifdef debug_AlwaysOne}
    aC.Execute;
    Result := 1;
    {$else}
    aC.Execute(Result, EmptyParam);
    {$endif}
  finally
    releaseADOCommand( aC );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If I call it with an uninitialized OLEVariant (you named it for EmptyParam), it says : "Parameter object is improperly defined. Incorrect or incomplete information was provided." What should I do with the OLEVariant before method call?

Comment: What do you mean you called it with an uninitailized OLEVariant? EmptyParam is a function which already exist in the System.Variants unit, which represents an unused optional parameter.

Comment: I just "created" a local variable of type OLEVariant.

Comment: Thank you Remy! It works fine with the call of EmptyParam.